# How to receive the information passed in SIP refer in Twilio

Tags: twilio, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, ibm-voice-gateway

I have configured the IBM voice agent to transfer the call to an actual physical phone number when the caller asks to be transferred to an agent and it is working fine. Now what I am wondering is if it is possible to transfer the call to a Twilio number and get the information passed in the SIP REFER message in User-to-User Information (UUI). I couldn't find any example of that anywhere.

The following is what I have done until now.

I have bought a Twilio number (for example, let's say the number that I have purchased is: +1XXXXXXXXX1) and followed the instructions given in [this](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/voice-agent?topic=voice-agent-connect#twilio-setup) link to transfer the call from the Twilio number to IBM voice agent.

Once a user asks to transfer to an agent, I am transferring the user to an actual phone number using the vgwAction as shown below.

```
{
   "output": {
       "text": {
           "values": [ "Please hold on while I connect you with a live agent." ],
           "selection_policy": "sequential"
       },
       "vgwAction": {
           "command": "vgwActTransfer",
           "parameters": {
                "transferHeader": "User-to-User",
                "transferHeaderVal": "12a345b6c7d8901234e5;encoding=hex;purpose=foo;content=bar",
                "transferTarget": "sip:+1XXXXXXXXX2\\@mysiptrunk.pstn.twilio.com"
            }
       }
   }
}
```

I have followed the instruction in the following articles.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/voice-agent?topic=voice-agent-call-transfer
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4U29/call_transfer.html

This call transfer is working fine and the call is successfully getting transferred to the number +1XXXXXXXXX2. +1XXXXXXXXX2 is also a Twilio number.

Now my question is, how can I receive the User-to-User header value passed by SIP REFER message when the call is received by +1XXXXXXXXX2. Also, I wanted to know if there is a possibility of eliminating the second number +1XXXXXXXXX2 altogether and just transfer the call from IBM Voice agent to a softphone so I don't have to buy another Twilio number.

Thanks,

Ankur Patel

Answer (score 1):

A SIP REFER request in this case is processed by the caller. The caller then initiates a new call to the target specified in the REFER request. As for how a new INVITE request is constructed by the caller is out of scope of Voice agent.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, that means that the REFER request will be processed by Twilio and then a new INVITE request will be constructed by the Twilio to forward it to the destination SIP. If that is the case, can someone who knows about Twilio let me know if Twilio forwards the information in the new INVITE message.

Comment: Can you please let me know if it is possible to transfer the call to a SIP phone instead of an actual phone number using voice gateway. I couldn't find any example of that sort.

Comment: Thats' correct. 
I'll try to find someone who's  familiar with Twillio to see whether it's possible to forward the headers in the new INVITE request.
As for your question regarding transferring a call to a SIP destination, can you please provide more details? Do you mean whether it's possible to transfer a call to a SIP device bypassing Twillio? (assuming that the original call was initiated via Twillio).

Comment: What I want is when the SIP REFER is sent from Watson to Twilio, is there any way to forward the call to a softphone without the need for purchasing another phone number. So in the softphone, we can display the information collected by Watson from the caller.

Comment: You can transfer a call from Twilio to your SIP softphone w/o purchasing a new Twilio #.

Comment: Are there any samples which show how to do that? I actually could not find any samples which show the call transfer functionality and how you can transfer information collected by Watson to the transfer target. If there are any samples which use some other telephony provider apart from Twilio then also that would be helpful.